# Route Audio from SPDIF Input to 5.1 USB Soundcard (raspbian)

Tags: raspbian, audio, alsa

So I'm very new to audio stuff, but my setup is the following:

Any HDMI device --(via HDMI)--> TV --(via SPDIF)--> USB Sound Card (input) --> RaspberryPi --> USB Sound Card (3x3.5mm Audio Jack (Front, Rear, Center)) -> Logitech Sound

[Visualization of my goal in alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrmnW.png)

My problem is routing the audio on the RaspberryPi. My understanding is that I need to decode the DolbyDigital or anything to be understandable for the output device? How do I keep the 5.1 sound from the TV and pass it to my 5.1 Sound System

========

Console Outputs:

aplay -L: https://pastebin.com/MCjMPjrY

aplay -l: https://pastebin.com/nSAp3eiV

Picture of the [Soundcard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySrKJ.png)

Comment: Try to find the ac3dec/a52dec tool somewhere.

Comment: Thank you but is there any advice how to use it in my scenario?